# Copy data to a new sheet excluding the last 4 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a table from sheet 1, defined by the area D21:O21, until the end – (minus) the last 4 lines.

I have a problem pasting results. In sheet 2 I have a table that feeds pivot charts. After I delete previous filled rows (with values) and paste new ones (new values) the table extends further than it is supposed to. It adds blank cells downstream as if the copied sheet 1 had more rows with values.

For example: Imagine that my table (in sheet 1) has 600 rows with values. If I paste to the table (in sheet 2) it extends further than 600 rows (approx. 10000). Instead of adding multiple empty lines I want 600 except last 4 lines = from top to 596 rows.

```
Sub Prime()

Dim Last_Row1 As Long, Last_Row2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Enter DATA here")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("DATA")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the lastrow of the data to copy
    Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the next empty row in order to paste the data
    ws1.Range("D21:O21" & Last_Row1).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Last_Row2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Resize` method on the `Range` object? Also `D21:O21` is a single row of data so not sure what you mean by discarding the last four rows?

Comment: `ws1.Range("D21:O21" & Last_Row1)` is probably wrong, did you mean `ws1.Range("D21:O" & Last_Row1)`? You can just subtract 4 from Last_Row1 then.

Comment: Vincent G Thaks It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Prime()
    Dim Last_Row1 As Long, Last_Row2 As Long, table As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Enter DATA here")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("DATA")

    Set table = ws1.Range("D21:O28")   // I arbitrarily set this to 8 rows

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the lastrow of the data to copy
        Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the next empty row in order to paste the data
        table.Resize(table.Rows.Count - 4, table.Columns.Count).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Last_Row2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sub Prime()

 Dim Last_Row1 As Long, Last_Row2 As Long
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Enter DATA here")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("DATA")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the lastrow of the data to copy
    Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the next empty row in order to paste the data
    ws1.Range("D21:O" & Last_Row1-4).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Last_Row2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Offset function to exclude the last 4 rows.

```
Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(-4,0).Row
```

When you copy the range, you should delete row indicator "21" behind column "O", otherwise, the code would not select till the last row. Like following:

```
ws1.Range("D21:O" & Last_Row1).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Last_Row2)
```